# Jquery: how to release all event handlers, dom changes?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to reset the current page ? free all event handlers, remove any CSS toggled by Jquery, in simpler words, restoring the page to the original state without refreshing ?

Comment: refresh/reload page. There's no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`refresh/reload page. There's no other way.` I commented to the OP's post.

But thinking of it, I think there's a way.

On the css part, animations are being done on the `style` attribute. Removing `style` attribute reset the element from the animation. But take note that if you were using `style` attribute to style your element, that will be erased too.

On the binding event, you may want to bind namespaced events. For example, binding click would look something like this,

```
$('#someID').bind('click.toBeRemove', function(){...})
```

So that removing events would be easy as `$('*').unbind('.toBeRemove')`. Leaving the other original events (in this example the click event).

When using plugins, use those that has `.destroy()` method which removes it functionality and style on the element.

But this is not 100% sure working. Just a theory. There's **NO** easy way doing this. - Yes! there's no `$(window).reset()` that would reset the page without reloading.

Comment: Always a good idea to hesitate a bit before giving an "it can't be done" comment/answer. :o) So why the namespacing on the event?

Comment: well for my purpose, removing all event handlers by iterating over every element was sufficient. thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's a solution - capture a clone of the `body` as it is before you've done anything to it, then when you need the reset, replace the entire `body` with this clone.

```
var original = $('body').clone();

$('#reset').click(function() {
    $('body').replaceWith(original);
});
```

Of course, this won't undo any changes you made elsewhere, such as in the `head`, but it's still slightly better than the other options you've got, right?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/uevrM/

**Edit:** Just realized, this also won't kill off any event handlers created with `live` or `delegate`. So again, no, this isn't 100% clean.

Comment: It should take care of `.delegate()` handlers in the sense that they won't fire anymore, since those are attached to their respective containers. What it doesn't do is clear any of the data/event handlers that jQuery stores. It would just disassociate it from the elements, so you would still want to delete that data. It is likely as simple as `delete jQuery.cache;` though.